# strange behaviour in interrupt handler

Tags: c, kernel, interrupt-handling, osdev

I am currently developing a kernel and run into a mysterious problem when implementing system call. I write the 0x80th interrupt handler like this:

```
sys_call_s:
    pushad
    call sys_call
    popad
    iret
```

"sys_call" is the name of the C function that do the real work. The problem is: I got a triple fault when executing the next instruction of "int 0x80". For example, I got a fault when executing the third line of the program below and finally bochs will reset itself.

```
abc: mov eax,0              ; 0 means system call get_pid()
     int 0x80
     mov [pid_father],eax   ; this is the instruction caused bochs to triple fault
     mov eax,1              ; 1: fork()
     int 0x80
     jmp $

pid_father:  dd 0
```

Even more strangly, when I substitute the "iret" instruction with "ret", the program works fine and spin itself at "jmp $".

Does anyone have any idea why I got this problem?

[edit] Now I think this problem is caused by the wrong address of the stack pointer. I have maped a page for this process, the physical address of this page is 0x401000, linear address is 0x800000(8M). I have set the stack pointer of this process to 0x800ff0, but each time I use "print-stack" command in bochs the output is: "physical address not available for linear 0x00801000". How can I fix it?

[edit] Now I found that I can't access data in this process. for example when I place "mov [pid_father],eax" before "int 0x80", bochs resets itself. why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to show the contents of your GDT and DS registers and paging tables. If you are seeing the triple fault on that line without any of the rest of the code, then that would imply that the access to [pid_father] is the problem. The data segment is invalid, or the page is invalid or marked read-only, which is causing a GPF or page fault exception. The GPF or page fault exception is failing (possibly for the same reason, or a different one), which is causing a double fault exception, which is again failing causing the CPU to triple fault and reset.

Bochs is usually pretty good (from memory) at printing out why it faulted. You may want to scroll up the history a little and look for the first exception that was raised.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, Stewart.

Comment: The problem locates in the page table. I didn't set the writable flag in the corresponding page table entry. So, every time I write to this page, I got a protection fault.

When using instruction "ret" to return from interrupt handler, the selector of the code segment is 0x10 which is the kernel's code selector, and code in this segment have right to read/write access to any page. This explains why the first process beheaviors right after substitute the "iret" instruction with "ret".

Comment: Really? I thought that page protection overrode selector protection, so that if the page tables are marked read only, the page is read only regardless of the current code segment. BTW - you didn't mention you had paging enabled. That would have been a useful thing to mention.

Comment: I have good reasons to believe that in this case, selector protection override page protection, alought 80386 programmer's reference manual(section 6.5) says that both protection level will be checked. But, let me explain: 1. the only differences between using "ret" or "iret" to return from an interrupt is the content of register "cs(ret:0x08, iret:0x1b)" and "ss(ret:0x10, iret:0x23)". and no protection exception occurs when using "ret" means that the content of "cs" and "ss" does matter. 2. in kernel code, you have rights to write all the pages regradless of their page flags.

Comment: 2 is simply not true. In kernel mode, you have the rights to change the page flags, for sure, but you can also set no-execute and read only bits and they will be honoured by the CPU raising the appropriate exceptions. But that is beside the point.

What does your GDT look like? Have you actually implemented user mode? The only way that 0x23 and 0x1b are good CS and SS values is if you have, but you don't mention that in the question. Also, what does the prototype of sys_call look like? Is it a C function?

Comment: I mean "user page" when I am saying "all the pages regradless of their page flags". The post is too long, I have to delete some words. I delete "call sys_call" when I am debugging and the same problem occured, so I believe this problem has nothing to with this function.

Comment: when copying the instructions to the pysical page allocated to the first process, that page is not marked as "writable", only "user" and "present", but the function that performs copying works fine.

Comment: "If the WP bit in CR0 is clear then your kernel code will be able to overwrite any pages even if you have marked the pages as read-only." [link]http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10898 I believe this is the answer we are looking for.

Comment: So the WP bit in CR0 is clear? Then the read/write status of the page is irrelevant. Anyhoo, without more information I can't help any more. My guess is that the iret is causing a GPF because you're trying to select a CS or SS which is incompatible with the EIP and ESP after the ret. That GPF is failing because your stack is hosed, which causes a double fault, which fails for the same reason causing a triple fault which reboots the CPU. Working out why that is happening needs more info that I have.